# Almost squared finite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

> **Definition.** A finite group $G$ is called *squared* (resp. *almost squared*) if there exists a subset $A\subseteq G$ such that $G=\{ab:a,b\in A\}$ and $|G|=|A|^2$ (resp. $|G|=|A|^2-1$). Such a set $A$ will be called an (*almost*) *square root* of $G$.

According to the answers to [this MO-post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/384292/61536), no nontrivial finite group is squared.

In contrast, nontrivial almost squared finite groups do exist. The simplest one is the 3-element cyclic group $C_3$. Any 2-element subset of $C_3$ is an almost square root of $C_3$.

A less trivial example is the dihedral group $D_8=\langle a,b\;|\;a^4=b^2=1,\;bab=a^3\rangle$ with almost square root $A=\{a,b,ba\}$.

Three other examples of almost squared groups (found by GAP) are:

$\bullet$ the symmetric group $S_4$;

$\bullet$ the general linear group $GL(2,3)$ of non-degenerate $2\times 2$ matrices over the 3-element field,

$\bullet$ the symmetric group $S_5$.

> **Problem 1.** Find more examples of almost squared finite group. Are there infinitely many almost squared finite groups?

**Remark.** Using GAP, Voldymyr Gavrylkiv established that among groups of order $<168$ the only almost squared groups are the groups $C_3$, $D_8$, $S_4$, $GL(2,3)$, and $S_5$. Those groups have orders 3, 8, 24, 48, and 120, respectively. It is interesting that no almost squared group of order 80 exists.

> **Problem 2.** What can be said about the structure of almost squared groups?

**Remark.** Alex Ravsky observed that for an almost square root $A$ of an almost squared group $G$, the center $Z(G)$ of $G$ is almost contained in the set $A^2=\{a^2:a\in A\}$ in the sense that $Z(G)\setminus A^2$ contains at most one element. So, $|Z(G)|\le|A|+1=1+\sqrt{|G|+1}$, which implies that the unique almost squared commutative group is $C_3$.

The only known (at the moment) almost squared noncommutative groups $D_8$, $S_4$ and $GL(2,3)$ have even cardinality.

> **Problem 3.** Is the cardinality of any almost squared noncommutative group even?

**Remark.** It can be shown that all noncommutative groups of odd order $<675=3^3\times 5^2$ are not almost squared.

> **Problem 3'.** Is there an almost squared group among groups of order $675$?

> **Problem 4.** Let $A$ be an almost square root of an almost squared non-commutative finite group $G$. Are there distinct elements $a,b\in A$ such that $a^2=b^2=g$ for some $g\in G$ such that:
> $\bullet$ $g\in Z(G)$? 
> $\bullet$ $g^2\in Z(G)$?
> $\bullet$ $g^2=1$?
> $\bullet$ $g=1$?
> $\bullet$ $g$ has order $\le 3$?

**Remark.** For any almost square root in any of three known almost squared noncommutative groups $D_8,S_4,GL(2,3)$, there exist distinct elements $a,b\in A$ such that $a^2=b^2=1$. In these group the center contains at most two elements.

The following problem was suggested by @LSpice in his comment.

> **Problem 5.** Let $G$ be an almost squared noncommutative group. Is $z^2=1$ for any central element of $G$?

Comment: I tried to extend the arguments in the representation ring. The eigenvalues of $\sum_{a \in A} a$ on every nontrivial irreducible representation of $a$ are roots of unity, since the eigenvalues of its square are roots of unity on these representations. Thus $|\operatorname{tr} (\sum_{a \in A} a, \dim V)| \leq \dim V$ for all nontrivial representations, so $\sum_v |\operatorname{tr} (\sum_{a \in A} a, \dim V)| ^2 \leq |A|^2 + |G|-1= 2 (n^2-1)$

Comment: which by orthogonality of characters implies that $A$ is reasonably evenly distributed among the conjugacy classes of $G$ - if I calculated right that the sum over conjugacy classes $C$ of $( | A \cap C| - |A| |C| /|G|)^2 / |C|$ is at most $(n^2-2)/(n^2-1)$, but this doesn't seem strong enough to lead to a classification.

Comment: @LSpice Right. Thank you. I corrected to "every".

Comment: What is an almost square root of $\mathrm S_4$?

Comment: Trivial observation:  if $A$ is an almost square root of $G$, then so is $z A$ for every $z \in \operatorname Z(G)$; so perhaps it makes sense to ask in **Problem 4** if some central translate of $A$ satisfies your condition—unless you are making the additional hypothesis that the centre of an almost squared group has exponent $2$?  (One could perhaps also ask about how many almost square roots there are; surely it would be too much to expect that they are all central translates of one another.)

Comment: @LSpice For the almost squared groups $D_8$ and $S_4$ the center indeed has exponent 2. GAP calculations show that $S_4$ has 96 almost roots. The simplest is $\{ a, b, c, ac, bc \}$ where $a,b,c$ are elements of $S_4$ such that $a^2=b^3=c^2=1$,  $ba=ab^2$, $(aca)^2=1$, $cb=baca$... GAP shows some strange presentation of $S_4$ (if the group (24,12) in GAP is indeed $S_4$). Maybe I will try to find the almost square root of $S_4$ by hands (using some more convenient presentations).

Comment: @LSpice I have added your question about order of central elements to Problem 4.

Comment: Where does Alex Ravsky's observation about the centre appear?

Comment: @LSpice This was a private communication from Ravsky and it concerned squared groups but the idea worked also for almost squared groups. In my partial answer (below) this Ravsky's observation is improved just a bit.

Comment: @LSpice You asked about the almost square root of $S_4$: the set of permutations $A={ (12),  (123),  (13)(24),  (1324),  (243) }$ is such a root (a personal communication by V.Gavrylkiv).

Comment: By the way, finding an almost square root where the identity shows up twice in $A.A$ (and every other element shows up once) necessitates finding a $(0,1)$-matrix $M$ such that $M^{2} = I + J$ where $J$ is the all-ones matrix. This is reminiscent of the problem of finding an incidence matrix for a projective plane, which is notoriously difficult in exceptional dimensions ( ie dimension $n^{2}+n+1$ with $n$ not a prime power).

Comment: Random observation: the examples here (and in the answers) all have $|G|=p^2-1$ for prime $p$; the non-example $|G|=80$ corresponds to a squaring set of size $9$. It'd be fascinating to know if there are any examples with $|G|=224$.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki An hour ago I have written exactly the same question to Kabenyuk (who can compute all those large groups without GAP, because GAP is too slow). I do not know what happens with 224 and also why there are no examples of almost squared groups of order 80 (how to prove this without brute force).

Comment: The two orders, in addition to being $n^2-1$, have very similar 'shape' — $2^4\cdot5$ and $2^5\cdot 7$ — so if there isn't a group of order 224 perhaps there's an explanation lurking there too.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki On the other hand, $24=2^3\cdot 3$ and $48=2^4\cdot 3$ are not exceptional, but $80=2^4\cdot 5$ is exceptional.

Answer (score 8):

Some preliminary comments. I may add more later: Let $G$ be any finite group. If $S$ is a subset of $G$, let $S^{+} = \sum_{s \in S} s$ in the group algebra $\mathbb{C}G$. Suppose that $G$ has an almost square root $A$. If $1 \in A$, then $1 a = a 1 $ for every $a \in A$, so that $|A| = 1 $ and $|G| = 3 $, so suppose from now on that $1 \not \in A$.
We have $(A^{+})^{2} = x + G^{+}$ for some $x \in G.$ Notice that $A^{+}$ commutes with $G^{+}$, so that $A^{+}$ commutes with $x$. Hence $xAx^{-1} = A$, so that the set $A$ is invariant under conjugation by $x$. Also we have $(x^{n}A^{+})^{2} = x^{2n+1} + G^{+}$ for every integer $n$, so that $x^{n}A$ is another almost square root for $G$. If the order of $x$ is not a power of $2$, then there is an integer $n$ such that the order of $x^{2n+1}$ is a power of $2$. Hence if $G$ has an almost square root, then we may arrange matters so that the order of $x$ is a power of $2$ (allowing the possibility of order $1$). In particular, we may arrange matters so that $x = 1$ when $G$ has odd order.

Now suppose that $x$ has $2$-power order greater than one. Let $a,b \in A$ with $x = ab.$ If $a,b \not \in C_{G}(x)$ then $x = a^{x}b^{x}$ is the only other factorization of $x$ as a product of two elements of $A$. If $a,b \in C_{G}(x)$ with $a \neq b$ then $x = ab = ba$ are the only expressions of $x$ as a product of two elements of $A$. If $a = b \in C_{G}(x)$ then there is exactly one more expression $c^{2} = x$ with $c \in A$ (since $x$ can't then be a product of two elements of $A$, each outside $C_{G}(x)).$

Now let $H = C_{G}(x)$ and $D = A \cap H.$ Suppose that $ d \in H $ with $d \neq x.$
Then $d = uv$ for some $u,v \in A$ and $u,v$ are unique. Then $d = d^{x} = u^{x}v^{x}$ and $u^{x},v^{x} \in A$. Hence $u = u^{x}$ and $v = v^{x}.$
Thus $u, v \in D$.

Now we have $(D^{+})^{2} = H^{+} \pm x $. If the product is $H^{+} + x,$ then $D$ is an almost square root  for $H = C_{G}(x).$

Suppose then $(D^{+})^{2} = H^{+}-x.$ Note that $H$ has even order as $x \in H$.
In the regular representation of $H$, the element $H^{+}- x$ has the eigenvalue $|H| - 1$ with multiplicity $1$, and $D^{+}$ has the eigenvector $|D|$ on that eiegenspace. Hence $|H|-1$ is the square of an odd integer. Thus $|H| \equiv 2$ (mod $8$). In that case, $\langle x \rangle$ is a Sylow $2$ subgroup of $H = C_{G}(x) = N_{G}(\langle x \rangle)$, so is also a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$.
This is a standard group-theoretic argument, but I explain it for non-group theorists : Note that $x$ lies in some Sylow $2$-subgroup $S$ of $G$. Suppose that $|S| > 2.$ If $x \in Z(S)$, then $S \leq C_{G}(x),$ so that $|S|$ divides $|H|$ which is not the case. If $x \not \in Z(S)$, then $\langle x, Z(S) \rangle \leq H$ and $|\langle x, Z(S) \rangle | \geq 2|\langle x \rangle |,$  a contradiction.

However, we can now reach a contradiction. If $G$ is a group of even order such that $A$ is an almost square root for $G$, then $|A|^{2} = |G| + 1$, so that $|G|+1$ is the square of an odd integer. Hence $|G| + 1 \equiv 1$ (mod $8$), so that $|G|$ is divisible by $8$.

But in the present case, $|G|$ is not divisble by $4$. Hence the situation $(D^{+})^{2} = H^{+} - x$ can not occur when $x$ is a non-identity element of $2$-power order of $G$, and $G$ has an almost square root $A$ such that
$(A^{+})^{2} = G^{+} + x$, where $H = C_{G}(x).$

In particular, we may deduce that if $G$ is a finite group of even order with an almost square root $A$ such that $(A^{+})^{2} = G^{+} + x$ for some non-identity element $x$ whose order is a power of $2$, then $D = A \cap C_{G}(x)$ is an almost square root for $H = C_{G}(x).$

To recap : if $G$ is a finite group with an almost square root $A$, and we have $(A^{+})^{2} = G^{+} + x$ for some non-identity element $x$, then we can find an integer  $n$ such that $x^{n}A$ is an almost square root for $G$ with $(x^{n}A^{+})^{2} = G^{+} + x^{2n+1}$, where the order of $x^{2n+1}$ is a power of $2$ (possibly $1$). This reduces to considering the case that the order of $x$ is a power of $2$ (possibly $1$). If the order of $x$ is a power of $2$ greater than one, the group $C_{G}(x)$ has the almost square root $D = A \cap C_{G}(x).$

Hence a key case to understand is when $x$ is a central element of $G$ whose order is a power of $2$ (possibly $1$).

Continued : Notice also that if $x$ has even order, then $|C_{G}(x)|$ is a group of even order with an almost square root, so that $|C_{G}(x)|$ has order divisible by $8$.

Comment: If $x=ab$ for some $a,b\in A\setminus C_G(x)$, then $xax^{-1}=x^{-1}ax$ and $xbx^{-1}=x^{-1}bx$ and hence $a,b\in C_G(x^2)$. Maybe this can be used somehow? For example that $A\cap C_G(x^2)$ is an almost square root of the subgroup $C_G(x^2)$?

Comment: If $(D^+)^2=H^+-x$, then $x^2=1$. Indeed, in this case $|H|=|D|^2+1$ and $|H|$ is even since $x\in H$ has 2-power order. Then $|D|=2m+1$ for some $m$ and hence $|H|=|D|^2+1=4(m^2+m)+2$ is not divisible by 4. So, the order of $x$ should be 2.

Comment: I noticed (even on the answers to my preceding "squared" question) that there is a kind of telepathy when different mathematicians on huge distances arrive to the same conclusions in the same time. By the way, it is not the end of the story. If $(D^+)^2=H^+-x$, then $x\in D$ and $H=C_G(x)$ is a 2-element group. Assuming that $x\notin D$, we can find an element $u\in D$ with $u^2=1$. Since $u$ and $x$ commute and $x^2=1$, they generate a 4-element subgroup of $H$, which implies that $|H|$ is divisible by 4, which is not true. Therefore $x\in D$.

Comment: Therefore $x\in D$ and since elements of $D$ do not commute, we conclude that $|D|=1$ and $H=\{1,x\}$. Therefore, if $(D^+)^2=H^+-x$, then $x\in D$, $x^2=1$ and $C_G(x)=\{1,x\}$.

Comment: I am trying to determine the smallest odd cardinality of a group for which it cannot be immediately shown that it is not almost squared. It seems that all groups of odd cardinality $3<4n^2-1<5^2\cdot 3^3$ are not almost squared.  So, finding such a group by brute force in GAP is a hopeless task. I do not know whether there is an almost squared group aboung groups of order $5^2\cdot 3^3$.

Comment: Unfortunately, this my argument does not work. It only proves what I already wrote earlier: if $x$ has order $2^n$, then $|G|$ is divisible by $2^{n+1}$. No so much.

Comment: Observe that for $f=(|A|\pm 1)\sum_{a\in A}a$ and $e=\sum_{g\in G}g$ we have $(f-e)^2=(|A|\pm 1)^2x$. Maybe this equality can be used to show that $x$ showld have small 2-power order? Maybe this recent result (https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.02586) about matrices could be of help?

Comment: I can also prove that $G$ is even and $a^2=b^2$ for two distinct $a,b\in A$, then the center of $G$ has even index in $G$. All non-commutative examples (i.e., $D_8$, $S_4$ and $GL(2,3)$ of almost squared groups show that exacty this happens: any almost square root contains two distinct elements $a,b$ with $a^2=b^2=1$.

Answer (score 6):

The following theorem yields a partial answer to Problem 2.

A subset $C$ of a group $G$ is called *unfree* if $xy=yx$ or $x^2=y^2$ for any elements $x,y\in C$.

For a group $G$ let $ucov(G)$ be the smallest cardinality of a cover of $G$ by unfree subsets of $G$.

> **Theorem 1.** If $A$ is an almost square root of an almost squared finite group $G$, then $$\sqrt{|G|+1}=|A|\le 1+ucov(G).$$

*Proof.* Let $A$ be an almost square root of $G$ and $\mathcal U$ be a cover of the group $G$ by unfree subsets such that $|\mathcal U|=ucov(G)$. We lose no generality assuming that the cover $\mathcal U$ consists of pairwise distinct sets.

**Claim.** There exists an element $a\in A$ such that for any distinct elements $x,y\in A\setminus\{a\}$ we have $xy\ne yx$ and $x^2\ne y^2$.

*Proof.* To derive a contradiction, assume that for any $a\in A$ there exist elements $x,y\in A\setminus\{a\}$ such that $xy=yx$ or $x^2=y^2$. For every $g\in G$ consider the set $P_g=\{(a,b)\in A\times A:ab=g\}$. By the definition of an almost square root, there exists a unique element $g\in G$ such that $|P_g|=2$ and $|P_x|=1$ for all $x\in G\setminus\{g\}$. Take any pair $(a,b)\in P_g$. By our assumption, there exist two distinct elements $x,y\in A\setminus\{a\}$ such that $xy=yx$ or $x^2=y^2$. It follows that the set $P_g$ coincides with $\{(x,y),(y,x)\}$ or $\{(x,x),(y,y)\}$, which implies that $a\in\{x,y\}$. But this contradicts the choice of $x,y$. $\quad\square$

Claim implies that for any $U\in\mathcal U$ we have $|U\cap (A\setminus\{a\})|\le 1$.
Consequently, $$|A|=1+|A\setminus\{a\}|\le 1+|\mathcal U|=1+ucov(G).\quad\square$$

Now it remains to find some upper bounds on the number $ucov(G)$.

For a group $G$ let $ccov(G)$ be the smallest cardinality of a cover of $G$ by cyclic subgroups. Since each cyclic group is an unfree set, we get the upper bound $ucov(G)\le ccov(G)$. Also $ccov(G)\le|G|-1$ for any nontrivial group $G$ and $ccov(G)\le|G|-2$ for any group which is not Boolean.

> **Lemma 1.** $ucov(G)\le ccov(G/Z(G))$.

*Proof.*  Let $Z=Z(G)$ be the center of $G$. Let $\kappa=ccov(G/Z)$ and $(C_\alpha)_{\alpha\in\kappa}$ be a cover of $G/Z$ by cyclic subgroups. For every $\alpha\in\kappa$ choose an element $c_\alpha\in G$ such that the coset $c_\alpha Z$ is a generator of the cyclic subgroup $C_\alpha$. Observe that for every $\alpha\in\kappa$ the set $U_\alpha=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb Z}c_\alpha^nZ$ is unfree and $\mathcal U=\{U_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in\kappa}$ is a cover of $G$ by unfree sets withessing that $$ucov(G)\le|\mathcal U|\le\kappa=|ccov(G/Z)|.\quad$$

> **Corollary.** If a finite noncommutative group $G$ is almost squared, then $|Z(G)|\le \sqrt{|G|+1}-1$.

*Proof.* Let $A$ be an almost square root of $G$. By Theorem 1 and Lemma 1, we have
$$|A|\le 1+ucov(G)\le 1+cc(G/Z(G))\le 1+|G/Z(G)|-1=|G|/|Z(G)|$$ and hence
$$|Z(G)|\le \frac{|G|}{|A|}=\frac{|A|^2-1}{|A|}=|A|-\frac1{|A|}$$ and finally
$$|Z(G)|\le -1+|A|=-1+\sqrt{|G|+1}.$$

> **Proposition 120.** If a non-commutative group $G$ of order 120 is almost squared, then $|Z(G)|\le 6$.

**Proof.** Let $Z=Z(G)$ be the center of the group $G$ and $A$ be an almost square root of $G$. By the preceding Corollary, $|Z|\le 10$. Assuming that $|Z|=10$, we conclude that the group $G/Z$ has order 12. Looking at [the classification of groups of order 12](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Groups_of_order_12), we can observe that $G/Z$ contains a cyclic subgroup of order $\ge 4$. Then $ccov(G/Z)\le 1+(12-4)=9$ and hence $11=|A|\le 1+ucov(G)\le 1+ccov(G/Z)\le 10$, which is not true. This contradiction shows that $|Z|<10$ and hence $|Z|\le 8$.

Assuming that $|Z|=8$, we conclude that the group $G/Z$ has order $15$ and hence is cyclic, which implies $11=|A|\le 1+ucov(G)\le 1+ccov(G/Z)=2$ and this is a contradiction. So, $|Z|<8$ and hence $|Z|\le 6$ (as $|Z|$ divides $|G|=120$).

> **Proposition 168.** If a non-commutative group $G$ of order 168 is almost squared, then $|Z(G)|\le 7$.

**Proof.** Let $Z=Z(G)$ be the center of the group $G$ and $A$ be an almost square root of $G$. By Corollary, $|Z|\le 12$. Assuming that $|Z|=12$, we conclude that the group $G/Z$ has order 14 and hence is cyclic. By Theorem 1, $$13=|A|\le 1+ucov(G)\le 1+ccov(G/Z)=2,$$which is a contradiction showing that $|Z|\ne 12$. Then $|Z|<12$ and hence $|Z|\le 8$ (11,10 and 9 do not divide $168=|G|$). If $|Z|=8$, then the group $G/Z$ has cardinality $168/8=21$ and hence is cyclic. Then $$13=|A|\le 1+ucov(G)\le 1+ccov(G/Z)=2,$$which is a contradiction showing that $|Z|\ne 8$. Therefore, $|Z|\le 7$.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another example of a group with an almost square root.
In a simple group $G$ of order 168 there exists a subset of 13 elements whose
square is equal to $G$.
We found several such subsets. Here is one of them.
Let $G=PSL(3,2)=SL(3,2)={\rm gr\,}((4,6)(5,7),(1,2,4)(3,6,5))$.
Then

$
A=\{
(1,2)(4,7),\
(1,4)(3,6),\
(1,2)(4,5,7,6),\
(1,2,3)(4,5,7),\
(1,2,3)(4,7,6),\\
(1,2,4,5,7,3,6),\
(1,2,4,7)(3,6),\
(1,2,6)(3,4,7),\
(1,2,6,3,4,5,7),\\
(1,5,2)(3,4,7),\
(1,5,2,3,6,4,7),\
(1,5,2,4,7,6,3),\
(1,5,2,6)(4,7)
\}
$

is an almost square root of $G$.
We can use the following GAP commands to check this fact:

`g:=PSL(3,2);`

`qr:=[ (1,2)(4,7), (1,4)(3,6), (1,2)(4,5,7,6), (1,2,3)(4,5,7), (1,2,3)(4,7,6), (1,2,4,5,7,3,6), (1,2,4,7)(3,6), (1,2,6)(3,4,7), (1,2,6,3,4,5,7), (1,5,2)(3,4,7), (1,5,2,3,6,4,7), (1,5,2,4,7,6,3), (1,5,2,6)(4,7)];;`

`prod:=[];; for a in qr do for b in qr do Add(prod,a*b);od;od;`

`Size(AsSet(prod));`

Briefly, our recursive algorithm uses the function $F(A)$:

1. We start the computation from a set $A$ consisting of two elements of order 2.
2. Suppose we have already computed a set $A$ such that
   $|A^2|\geq|A|^2-1$.
3. We compute the set of candidates $C$ by the rule

$C=G\setminus(A^{-1}A^2\cup A^2A^{-1}\cup N_G(A)\cup S(A))$,

where
$N_G(A)=\{x\in G\,\mid\,x^{-1}Ax\cap A\neq\emptyset \}$ and
$S(A)=\{x\in G\,\mid\,x^2\in A^2\}$.

4. After that, for each $x\in C$ we compute $A'=\{A,x\}$ and run $F(A')$.

Note that, there are actually exactly three (up to conjugacy)
pairs of elements of order 2 in the group $G$:
$(12)(47),\ (15)(26)$;
$(12)(47),\ (14)(36)$;
$(12)(47),\ (13)(46)$.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Our GAP-program still calculates exactly this group. It is calculaing already 2 weeks and we estimate that it will require another 2 weeks to finish. So, you are a winner in this GAP-race. Our congratulations!

Comment: Which algorithm have you applied for finding the almost square root of GL(3,2) and how powerful was your computer? Because we use GAP, which is rather slow for such a task.

Comment: My computer is pretty weak compared to today's standards.
Operating System: Windows XP,Processor: GenuineIntel ~3192 GHz, Memory: 4096MB RAM.
I haven't used GAP for calculations.
The running time depends on the initial pair of elements of order 2
from a few seconds to 80 minutes.
I will add to my answer a brief description of the algorithm.

Comment: We used exactly the same algorithm, but applied it with GAP, which slows everything down.

Answer (score 2):

**Simple group of order 360**

Another good example of an almost square simple group
is the alternating group $A_6$ of order $360=19^2-1$.
In order to check that the set $A$ below is an almost square root of $A_6$,
you can use the following **GAP** commands:

```
g:=AlternatingGroup(6);;
A:=[(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(5,6),(1,2,3,4)(5,6),(1,2,3),(1,3,4),
(1,2)(3,4,5,6),(1,2)(3,4,6,5),(1,2,3,4,5),(1,2,3,4,6),
(1,2,5)(3,4,6),(1,2,5,3,4),(1,2,5,6)(3,4),(1,2,5,6,3),
(1,2,6)(3,4,5),(1,2,6,3,4),(1,2,6,5)(3,4),(1,2,6,5,3),
(1,3,4,5,6),(1,3,4,6,5)];;
Size(A);
prod:=[];;
for a in A do for b in A do Add(prod,a*b);od;od;    
Size(AsSet(prod));
```

Note that the subset
$$
V=\{(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(5,6),(1,2,3,4)(5,6),(1,2,3),(1,3,4)\}\subset A
$$
is an almost square root of a group isomorphic to the symmetric group $S_4$.
The set $V$ is an initial set from which our algorithm starts.
We next consider the following three 5-element subsets of $A_6$:
\begin{eqnarray*}
V_1&=&\{(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(5,6),(1,2,3,4)(5,6),(1,2,3),(1,3,4)\},\\
V_2&=&\{(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(5,6),(1,2,3,4)(5,6),(1,3,2),(2,3,4)\},\\
V_3&=&\{(1,2)(3,4),(1,3)(5,6),(1,2,3,4)(5,6),(1,4,2),(2,4,3)\}.
\end{eqnarray*}
Each of these subsets has the following three properties:
(1) $V_i$ is an almost square root of a group isomorphic to $S_4$;
(2) $V_i$ has a subset with three elements which is an almost square
root of a group isomorphic to the dihedral group $D_4$ of order 8;
(3) $V_i$ contains two elements of order 2.

It turns out that any 5-subset of $A_6$
with these three properties is conjugate
to one of $V_i$ or $V_i^{-1}$ under the group Aut$(A_6)$.
Each set $V_i$ is complemented to an almost square root of $A_6$.

**Groups of odd order**

It seems to me that the answer to Problem 3' is negative.

**Proposition.**
*Any group of order $675$ is not an almost squared group.*

*Proof*.
This is a straightforward consequence of Lemmas 1 and 2.

**Lemma 1.**
*Let $G$ be a group of odd order and $|G|>3$.
If $G$ has an almost square root, then $Z(G)=\{e\}$.*

*Proof*.
Let $A$ be an almost square root of $G$.
Then there exists exactly one element $x\in G$
which can be represented as the product $x=ab$, $a,\,b\in A$ in exactly two ways.
We will call this element *a singular element* of group $G$
with respect to the almost square root $A$.
All the other elements of group $G$ are represented uniquely as the product
of two elements of $A$.

If $Z(G)\neq\{e\}$ and $z\in Z(G)$, $z\neq e$,
then there are two possible cases, either $z=a^2$ where $a\in A$ or $z=ab$, $a\neq b$ and $a,b\in A$.

In the first case we have $z=a^2$. Since the order of $G$ is odd, it follows that $a\in Z(G)$ and $ab=ba$ for each $b\in A$. Hence $|A|=2$ and $|G|=3$.

In the second case we have $z=ab=ba$ and $z$ is singular element.
Since there is exactly one singular element, the equality $z^2=a'b'$ with $a',b' \in A$, $a'\neq b'$, is  impossible. Then $z^2=a'^2$, $a'\in A$, and we are back to the first case.
This is a contradiction and the lemma is proved.

**Lemma 2.**
*Let $G$ be a group of order $675=3^3\cdot5^2$.
Then $Z(G)\neq\{e\}$.*

*Proof*.
Using the small groups library of **GAP**
we can prove of Lemma 2 by the following **GAP**
commands:

```
a:=AllSmallGroups(675);;
Filtered(a,x->Size(Center(x))=1);
```

However, the same can easily be proved without **GAP**.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and the last example of an almost squared group. So, now we know 7 such groups: $C_3$, $D_8$, $S_4$, $GL(2,3)$, $S_5$, $GL(3,2)$, $A_6$. And this is great!

Comment: In the proof of Lemma 1 it is not clear why $z^2=a^2b^2=b^2a^2$ leads to a contradiction ($a^2,b^2$ need not belong to $A$). On the other hand, we can use the fact that $1$ is a unique singular elements of an almost squared group of odd order.

Comment: I agree with you. I'll edit my post now.

Answer (score 1):

Here are additional considerations for groups with an almost square root.
This is a development of the idea of Taras Banakh.

Let $G$ be a finite group.
The following graph $\Gamma=\Gamma(G)$ associated with group $G$ is useful.
The graph $\Gamma$ has as vertex set the elements of the group $G$,
two vertices $x$, $y$, $x\neq y$, being joined if $xy = yx$ or $x^2=y^2$.
A subset $X$ of the vertices of $\Gamma$ is called an independent set
if the induced subgraph on $X$ has no edges.
The independence number of $\Gamma$ is the maximum size of
an independent set of vertices and is denoted by $\alpha(\Gamma)$.

**Lemma.**
*If $A$ is an almost square root of $G$, then $|A|\leq\alpha(\Gamma(G))+1$.*

Here is an example of application of the lemma.
There are a total of 190 non-Abelian groups of order $224=15^2-1$.
For each of them the graph $\Gamma$ and its independence number
are calculated using the GAP and GRAPE packages.
The maximum independence number for these groups is $10<16$.

```
RequirePackage( "grape" );
A:=[];;
all:=AllSmallGroups(224,IsAbelian,false);;
for g in all do
    v:=SortedList(g);;
    A:=NullMat(Size(v),Size(v));;
    for x in v do for y in v do if x*y=y*x and x<>y then A[Position(v,x)][Position(v,y)]:=1;fi;od;od;
    for x in v do for y in v do if x^2=y^2 and x<>y then A[Position(v,x)][Position(v,y)]:=1;fi;od;od;
    gamma:=Graph(Group(()), [1..Size(v)], OnPoints,function(x,y) return A[x][y]=1; end, true );;
    root:=IndependentSet( gamma );;
    Print(Position(all,g),", ", Size(root),", ", StructureDescription(g),"\n");
od;
```

Comment: Maybe it is reasonable to define almost independent sets (with at most one edge) and improve Lemma to $|A|\le \alpha_1(\Gamma(G))$ where $\alpha_1(\Gamma)$ is the largest cardinality of an almost independent set in the graph $\Gamma(G)$.

Answer (score 0):

The following theorem gives a partial answer to Problem 2 on the structure of almost squared groups. Let us recall that the *Abelianization* of a group $G$ is the quotient group $G/[G,G]$ of $G$ by its commutator subgroup.

> **Theorem.** Let $G$ be an almost squared group and $R$ be an almost square root of $G$. Let $H=[G,G]$ be the commutator subgroup of $G$ and $A=G/H$ be the Abelianization of $G$. Then there exists $\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}$ such that:
>
> 1. $|A|$ divides $|R|+\epsilon$.
> 2. The set $L=\big\{gH\in A:|R\cap gH|=\frac{|R|+\epsilon}{|A|}\big\}$ has cardinality $|L|=|A|-1$.
> 3. For the unique element $gH$ of the singleton $A\setminus L$ we have $|R\cap gH|=\frac{|R|+\epsilon}{|A|}-\epsilon$.

*Proof.* For a subset $S\subseteq G$ let $\sum S$ be the element $\sum_{x\in S}x$ in the group algebra $\mathbb C G$. Taking into account that $R$ is an almost square root of $G$, we conclude that $(\sum R)^2=\sum G+s$ for some element $t\in G$ (having two representations as products of elements of the set $R$).

In the group algebra $\mathbb C A$ of the Abelianization $A=G/H$, consider the element $y=\sum_{gH\in A}|R\cap gH|\cdot gH$. Since $R$ is an almost square root of $G$,  $(\sum R)^2=\sum G+t$ for some elememt $t\in G$ (that has a double representation as a product of two elements in $R$). The equality $(\sum R)^2=\sum G+t$ implies $y*y=|H|\cdot\sum A+\tau$ where $\tau=tH\in A$.  Now consider the elements $z=y-\frac{|R|\pm1}{|A|}\sum A$ of $\mathbb C A$ and observe that
$$
\begin{aligned}
z*z&=(y-\tfrac{|R|\pm1}{|A|}\sum A)*(y-\tfrac{|R|\pm1}{|A|}\sum A)=\\
&=y*y-\tfrac{|R|\pm1}{|A|}\sum_{b\in A}y*b-\tfrac{|R|\pm1}{|A|}\sum_{b\in A}b*y+\tfrac{(|R|\pm1)^2}{|A|^2}\sum_{a,b\in A}ab=\\
&=|H|\cdot\sum A+\tau-\tfrac{|R|\pm1}{|A|}\sum_{a,b\in A}|R\cap a|\cdot (ab+ba)+\tfrac{(|R|\pm1)^2}{|A|}\sum A=\\
&=\tfrac{|H|\cdot|A|+(|R|\pm1)^2}{|A|}\cdot\sum A+\tau-2\tfrac{|R|\pm1}{|A|}|R|\sum A=\\
&=\tfrac{|G|+|R|^2\pm2|R|+1-2(|R|\pm1)|R|}{|A|}\sum A+\tau=\\
&=\tfrac{|R|^2-1-|R|^2+1}{|A|}\sum A+\tau=\tau.
\end{aligned}
$$

Let $\hat z$ be the Fourrier transformation of $z$. It is the function assigning to every character $\chi:A\to\mathbb C$ the complex number $$\hat z(\chi)=\sum_{a\in A}z(a)\chi(a)$$where $z=\sum_{a\in A}z(a)\cdot a$. Since the function $\hat \tau$ has absolute value $1$ at each character, $\hat z\cdot \hat z=\widehat{z{*}z}=\hat \tau$, the function $\hat z:\hat A\to\mathbb C$ also has its values in the unit circle and hence $\hat z$ has norm $1$ in the Hilbert space $\mathbb C\hat A$ endowed with the inner product
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\frac1{|A|}\sum_{a\in \hat A}f(a)\cdot\overline{g(a)}.$$
Endow the group algebra $\mathbb C A$ with the inner product
$$\langle f,g\rangle=\sum_{a\in A}f(a)\cdot\overline{g(a)}.$$
Since the Fourrier transformation is an isometry isomorphism of the Hilbert spaces $\mathbb C A$ and $\mathbb C\hat A$, we obtain that
$$
(\star)\quad\|z\|^2=\sum_{a\in A}\big||R\cap a|-\tfrac{|R|\pm 1}{|A|}\big|^2=\|\hat z\|=1.
$$
Since $|A|$ divides $|G|=|R|^2-1$, the number $\frac{|R|}{|A|}$ is not integer. Let $\varepsilon>0$ be the smallest natural number such that $\frac{|R|+\varepsilon}{|A|}$ is integer.

The equation ($\star$) implies that for every $a\in A=G/H$ the number $|R\cap a|$ is equal either to $\frac{|R|+\varepsilon}{|A|}$ or to $\frac{|R|+\varepsilon}{|A|}-1$. Let
$$P=\{a\in A:|R\cap a|=\tfrac{|R|+\varepsilon}{|A|}\}\quad\mbox{and}\quad
Q=\{a\in A:|R\cap a|=\tfrac{|R|+\varepsilon}{|A|}-1\}.$$
Then the equation ($\star$)reduces to the equation
$$(\star\star)\quad
\begin{aligned}
|A|^2&=|P|\cdot(\varepsilon\mp1)^2+|Q|\cdot(\varepsilon\mp1-|A|)^2=\\
&=|P|\cdot(\varepsilon\mp 1)^2+|Q|\cdot(\varepsilon\mp 1)^2-2|Q|\cdot|A|\cdot (\varepsilon\mp1)+|Q|\cdot|A|^2=\\
&=|A|\cdot(\varepsilon\mp 1)^2-2|Q|\cdot|A|\cdot(\varepsilon\mp1)+|Q|\cdot|A|^2
\end{aligned}
$$
as $|P|+|Q|=|A|$.

Subtracting the equations ($\star$) for different signs after $\varepsilon$, we obtain obtain that $\varepsilon=|Q|$. After substitution of $\varepsilon=|Q|$ into the equation ($(\star\star$) we obtain that $\varepsilon=|Q|$ is equal to $1$ or $|A|-1$.

If $\varepsilon=|Q|=1$, then $|A|$ divides $|R|+\varepsilon=|R|+1$. If $\varepsilon=|Q|=|A|-1$, then $|A|$ divides $|R|+\varepsilon=|R|+|A|-1$ and hence divides $|R|-1$. Put $\epsilon=1$ if $\varepsilon=1$ and $\epsilon=-1$ if $\varepsilon=|A|-1$. In both cases we obtain that $|A|$ divides $|R|+\epsilon$.

Observe that $$|H|=\frac{|G|}{|A|}=\frac{|R|^2-1}{|A|}=\frac{|R|+\epsilon}{|A|}(|R|-\epsilon),$$
which means that $|H|$ is divisible by $|R|-\epsilon$.

If $|Q|=1$, then $\epsilon=1$, the set $$L=\{gH\in A:|R\cap gH|=\tfrac{|R|+\epsilon}{|A|}\}=|P|$$ has cardinality $|P|=|A|-|Q|=1$, and
$$\{gH:|R\cap gH|=\tfrac{|R|+\epsilon}{|A|}-\epsilon\}$$ is a singleton.

If $|Q|=|A|-1$, then $\epsilon=-1$, the set
$$\{gH:|R\cap gH|=\tfrac{|R|+|A|-1}{|A|}-1\}=
\{gH:|R\cap gH|=\tfrac{|R|+\epsilon}{|A|}\}=L$$
has cardinality $|A|-1$.

On the other hand, the set
$$P=\{gH\in A:|R\cap gH|=\tfrac{|R|+|A|-1}{|A|}\}=\{gH\in A:|R\cap gH|=\tfrac{|R|+\epsilon}{|A|}-\epsilon\}$$ is a singleton.